# get iTunes player state in AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I have this problem:
On running this script in the Script-Editor it works perfectly.

```
tell application "iTunes"
set playerstate to get player state
end tell
display dialog playerstate
```

I get s player state `running`, `stopped` or `paused`.
But if I export the script a application, I get something like `kPSS`.

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`player state` is a enumerated constant (actually an integer).
Just coerce the value to text

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set playerstate to (get player state) as text
end tell
display dialog player state
```

**Edit:**

This should work also with an applet

```
   tell application "iTunes"
        if player state is paused then
            set playerStateText to "Paused"
        else if player state is playing then
            set playerStateText to "Playing"
        else
            set playerStateText to "Stopped"
        end if
    end tell
    display dialog playerStateText
```

Comment: I does not works, with your script the result is `«constant ****kPSS»`